# tastypie group by value

Tags: django, group-by, tastypie

Using tastypie. I have the following simple model:

```
class Autocomplete(models.Model):
    tablename = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True) #
    fieldname = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True) #
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True) #

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'autocomplete'
```

And the following ModelResource:

```
class AutocompleteResource(ModelResource):
    counter = fields.CharField()

    class Meta:
        queryset = Autocomplete.objects.values('fieldname').annotate(counter=Count('fieldname'))
        resource_name = 'autocomplete'
```

My goal is to group by the fieldname and return a result like this:

```
fieldname  | counter 
-----------+-------
somefield1 |   177
somefield2 | 13926
somefield3 |  7331
```

Instead, tastypie throws back the following:

```
error_message: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''",
```

I'm probably missing something very basic here. Is it looking for the id but can't find it, because the values() call has removed it? How can I return a result that has different fields than the original model?

I've spent way too much trying to figure this out, hope you guys can point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using dehydrate. The code will look something like this:

```
class AutocompleteResource(ModelResource):
    counter = fields.CharField(readonly=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Autocomplete.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'autocomplete'

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(AutocompleteResource, self).get_object_list(request).annotate(counter=Count('fieldname', distinct=True))

    def dehydrate_counter(self, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.counter
```

Another way is passing 'counter' as an attribute:

```
class AutocompleteResource(ModelResource):
    counter = fields.CharField(readonly=True, attribute='counter')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Autocomplete.objects.values('fieldname').annotate(counter=Count('fieldname'))
        resource_name = 'autocomplete'
```

This comes from the doc:

> Optionally accepts an attribute, which should be a string of either an instance attribute or callable off the object during the  dehydrate or push data onto an object during the hydrate. Defaults to None, meaning data will be manually accessed.